# Android studio navigate between editors windows

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have split a window horizontally.

Is there a hotkey that allows be to jump between different window splits.

I could not find one in the keymap settings....there are so many!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac shortcut is Alt + Tab
On Windows the shortcut is not set by default.

You can set/check it by looking for "GoTo Next Splitter" in Settings -> Keymap

[image: Intellij Shortcut screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

- Toggle Between 2 windows (most recent): <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.
- Toggle Between 2 tabs (most recent): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.
- Recent Files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.
- Recently edited Files: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.
- Navigate to any file/directory: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. 
  If you want to find any folder/directory enter '`/`' to the start of the search phrase. And you can use wild-cards too. Ex: you don't remember exact file name in full but, some part (let say some file name ends with term '`provider`') just enter '`*provider`' as search text.